# Is there a way to retrieve code coverage metrics generated from OpenCover back to Jenkins?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, jenkins, sonarqube, opencover

I'm working on a .NET project that uses `Jenkins` as the CI server. The server is working as it's supposed to but now I'm trying to make it emit alerts in case of **low code coverage**.

The approach that I'm trying is to use `Sonar` to execute `NUnit` and `OpenCover`, but I need to link the **code coverage** metrics from `Sonar` back to `Jenkins` and that's where the problem resides.

AFAIK the report generated from `OpenCover` (**coverage-report.xml**) as is, is not recognized from `Jenkins` so what I'm trying to do is to make them talk by a xsl file that transforms the (**coverage-report.xml**) to a (**emma-report.xml**) that `Jenkins` has plugins that understands.

Although I don't know it that is the best approach. **Better approaches are more than welcome ;)** I'm facing a problem to get the `block coverage` metrics from OpenCover (`Emma` needs this metric).

I've managed to transform all other metrics needed `class, %`, `method, %` and `line, %` from `OpenCover` to `Emma`, but I'm not sure if is possible to get the `block, %` from the report.

**Can anyone tell me if it is possible or if there is a better approach to achieve what I'm trying to do (that is, make `Jenkins` emit build alerts when code coverage is bellow a certain percentage)?**

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running OpenCover from the sonar gallio plugin (from the [sonar C# ecosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Ecosystem)), a simple solution to get alerts on low code coverage could be the sonar [build breaker plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin).
You would get a broken build when coverage get below an alert threshold. This solution does not allow to get graph or trends in jenkins, but again if you use sonar, you have everything in the sonar dashboards.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is now a tool to convert OpenCover reports to Covertura XML
https://github.com/danielpalme/OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter/tree/master/OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter

The thread discussing this.

http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/discussions/398788